# Can I load this ubuntu on a mac ppc laptop running osx 10.5.8 and if not is there a version that I can?

Tags: mac

Can I load this ubuntu on a mac 1.5 ghz ppc g4 laptop with 1.5 gb ddr sdram running osx 10.5.8 and if not is there a version that I can?  It is a 17" non intel silver power pc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a version of Ubuntu for PPC Macs. Get it here:

Torrent: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso.torrent

Direct download: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso